# How do I inject a variable into an EJS template with Node.js + Express3?

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to be able to use Underscore.js from within my EJS templates, like this:

```
<% _.each(articles, function(article){ %>
    <section>
      <h2><%= title %></h2>
      <%= body %>
    </section>
    <hr/>
<% }) %>
```

I could inject it for every single route like so...

```
var _ = require('underscore');
exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { _: _, articles: app.allArticles() });
};
```

But that's tedious and prone to human error. Is there a general solution for this, to inject it for all views, all of the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this whith [app.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals).

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.locals._ = _;
// some code
app.listen(3000);
```